# React Native error for .git repo EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\App Development\deliveroo\.git\objects\maintenance.lock'

Tags: reactjs, git, react-native

i got an error in React Native server by Expo for .git directory

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\App Development\deliveroo\.git\objects\maintenance.lock'  
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at D:\App Development\deliveroo\node_modules\metro-file-map\src\watchers\NodeWatcher.js:278:14
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'lstat',
  path: 'D:\\App Development\\deliveroo\\.git\\objects\\maintenance.lock'
}
```

Howw to fix this

Tried many solutions related to file permissions but it is a issue in .git/objects directory wih maintainence.lock file , Strange thing is this maintainence.lock file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I finally solved it through clearing my npm cache:

```
npm cache clean --force
```